# Como borrar registros con mas de 7 días automáticamente?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un scritp php que carga unos datos, y quiero aprovecharlo para al mismo tiempo eliminar los registros mayores a 7 días de otra tabla. estuve buscando la manera, pero no se implementarla en mi script.

La idea es que cuando yo invoque este PHP, aprovecharlo para eliminar los registros de otra tabla mayores a 7 días automáticamente.

Mi archivo PHP

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM escolar_tracker order by id DESC";
require_once('conn.php');

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

 array_push($result,  array(

'ruta' => $row[ 'ruta' ],
    'jornada' => $row[ 'jornada' ]
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Ejemplo que encontré (pero no se implementarlo en mi actual script PHP)

**FECHA es TIMESTAMP**

```
DELETE FROM registros
WHERE fecha < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

Como podría implementarlo?

Comment: Ni siquiera dices en tu pregunta de qué tipo es tu columna `fecha`... ¿es del tipo `DATETIME`, es del tipo `TIMESTAMP`, es de otro tipo? Es fundamental para proporcionar una respuesta.

Comment: perfecto ya acutalizo

Comment: Prueba si así funciona: `DELETE FROM registros
WHERE fecha < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Comment: A. Cedano, la duda que tengo es como introduzco ese codigo en mi scritp, crearia otra query como: `$sql2 = "DELETE FROM registros..."` ? gracias

Comment: Sí claro, si quieres que esa consulta se ejecute cada vez que se ejecuta el script sólo es cuestión de escribir esa consulta y mandarla a ejecutar con `query`, aprovechando la misma conexión que usas para la otra consulta. Por ejemplo: `$sqlDelete="DELETE FROM ..."; Y luego: `$del= mysqli_query($con,$sqlDelete);` y si quieres puedes usar la función de filas afectadas para informar sobre la cantidad de filas que fueron borradas. Yo había entendido que era la consulta lo que no funcionaba.

Answer (score 1):

He estado probando tu consulta de borrado y no funciona. Te voy a proponer un código usando una consulta que sí funciona.

Además voy a aprovechar para optimizar el código en varios puntos:

- En lugar de seleccionar todas las columnas, seleccionaremos solamente aquellas que se necesitan.
- MySQLi tiene funciones específicas para traer los datos en arrays asociativos, conviene usar esas funciones, en lugar de usar algo genérico para luego tirar de otras funciones de PHP para hacer algo que ya tenemos incorporado en la API mysqli

Esta es la propuesta de código:

```
<?php 
    require_once('conn.php');

    $sql = "SELECT ruta, jornada FROM escolar_tracker order by id DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
            $result[]=$row;
        }

    /*Borrar datos*/
    $sqlDelete="DELETE FROM registros WHERE fecha < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY";
    $rsDelete=mysqli_query($con,$sqlDelete);
    /*
        Aquí puedes usar la cantidad de filas afectadas
        y poner ese dato en una clave de $result si te interesa
    */

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Soy estudiante de PHP, que pasa cuando consulto todas las columnas?, hace mas lento el scritp, es mejor siempre seleccionar lo necesario?

Comment: Lo hace más lento y usa más memoria en la lectura de los datos. Si necesitas solamente dos columnas y la tabla tiene `n` columnas, donde `n` puede ser `3` o puede ser `100`, significa que estás trayendo a memoria `n` columnas en vez de 2, que son las que necesitas. Cuando abres el `while` vas a estar leyendo un array con `n` columnas. Si son pocos datos se nota poco, pero siempre se nota. Además en el servidor se ejecutan infinidad de procesos (imagina una página web con miles o millones de usuarios), mientras más memoria ahorres, mejor. La optimización del código es importante siempre.

Comment: super, comprendo, seguire esas instrucciones en mis tareas, muchisimas gracias por la leccion

Comment: @AndresArango de nada. Me alegro de que te haya ayudado servido. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: talves seria adecuado usar triggers para que la eliminacion sea automatica

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

Si no necesitas los registros a eliminar, haces la acción antes del SELECT para no traes registros innecesarios. Haces un segundo SQL en donde este la sentencia que necesitas

```
<?php 
require_once('conn.php');


$sql_2 = "DELETE FROM registros WHERE fecha < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))";
mysqli_query($con, $sql_2);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM escolar_tracker order by id DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

 array_push($result,  array(

'ruta' => $row[ 'ruta' ],
    'jornada' => $row[ 'jornada' ]
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```